# Запрос отчета Прибыльность из MySklad JSON API с указанием входных параметров

Tags: moysklad-json-api

Интерфейс работы MySklad JSON API предусматривает возможность запроса отчета Прибыльность по адресу https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/report/profit/byproduct

Web-интерфейс этого отчета позволяет указывать множество входных параметров. Документация API не содержит вообще никаких входных параметров для этого отчета, по дефолту возвращается результат за 30 (видимо) дней. Как задать входной интервал выборки данных при запросе отчета Прибыльность через JSON API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В описании запроса [отчета](https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/doc/index.html#%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC-get) есть заговолок **URI Parameters**, справа от него есть ссылка Показать. Клик по ней разворачивает список  доступных параметров.

Интервал задается двумя параметрами **momentFrom** и **momentTo**. Формат строки: `ГГГГ-ММ-ДД ЧЧ:ММ:СС[.ммм]`, Часовой пояс: MSK (Московское время)